# "FOR UPDATE is not allowed with aggregate functions" in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, select-for-update

Here is pseudo code for what I'm trying to do:

```
rate_count = SELECT COUNT(id) FROM job WHERE last_processed_at >= ?

current_limit = rate_limit - rate_count
if current_limit > 0
  UPDATE job SET state='processing'
  WHERE id IN(
    SELECT id FROM job
    WHERE state='pending'
    LIMIT :current_limit
  )
```

I have it working except for concurrency issues. When run from multiple sessions at the same time, both sessions SELECT and therefore update the same stuff :(

I'm able to get the 2nd query atomic by adding FOR UPDATE in it's SELECT subquery. But I can't add FOR UPDATE to the first query because FOR UPDATE isn't allowed with aggregate functions

How can I make this piece an atomic transaction?

Comment: `select for update .. skip locked`: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This looks very promising!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This doesn't help solve my problem at all, it just makes FOR UPDATE more optimized, but thanks anyway for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do FOR UPDATE within a subquery:

```
rate_count := COUNT(id) 
              FROM (
                SELECT id FROM job
                WHERE last_processed_at >= ? FOR UPDATE
                ) a;
```

You can also do this whole thing in a single query:

```
UPDATE job SET state='processing'
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM job
  WHERE state='pending'
  LIMIT (SELECT GREATEST(0, rate_limit - COUNT(id))
         FROM (SELECT id FROM job
               WHERE last_processed_at >= ? FOR UPDATE) a
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR: FOR UPDATE is not allowed with aggregate functions

Because I use `count()` and `FOR UPDATE` as shown below:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM person FOR UPDATE;
```

So, I changed the query above to **one of 2 queries** below:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM person FOR UPDATE) AS result;
```

```sql
WITH result AS (SELECT * FROM person FOR UPDATE) SELECT count(*) FROM result;
```

Then, I could use `count()` and `FOR UPDATE` together:

```
 count
-------
     7
(1 row)
```